# TYPO3 Exception: Could not determine pid

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-9.x

While trying to add a new `fe_users` record, on save I get

```
(1/1) Exception
Could not determine pid
```

It's TYPO3 9.5.20.

We already have a lot of entries in multiple folders which could be edited without problem.
But those records were imported (by EXT:ig_ldap_sso_auth or with mysql terminal)

These records are used only to be shown (no login is used).

What configuration is missing or could be wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

as @biesior mentioned: the error message does not come from the core but from an extension. It's `EXT:solrfal` (in version 7.0.0)

Comment: This exception message `Could not determine pid` doesn't seem to exist in TYPO3 9.x core, probably in some 3rd part ext. Try to search for this and debug what causes that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real error was not in `EXT:solrfal`. this extension just hides the error with a misleading message.

The real reason was a wrong database configuration for the table `fe_users`. Although it is not possible in SQL to have a default value for fields of type `text` (and any given value is ignored) TYPO3 expects a default value if it is configured. As this is not returned from the database it assumes an error. And `EXT:solrfal` hooks into the error handling and assumes a wrong error.

Comment: Yes, just put in comment the ligne 327 in typo3conf/ext/solrfal/Classes/Queue/ConsistencyAspect.php witch throw the error, and you will see the real error origin

Answer (score 0):

Hi just got the same problem.

The error message was called in solrfal ConsistencyAspect::getRecordPageId() which was called by ConsistencyAspect::getDetectorsForSiteExclusiveRecord(). I remember that I have added various tablenames to siteExclusiveRecordTables of Extension Settings of solrfal. And yes, there was one table without pid. After removing this table from list, deleting files works again.